# How do I exclude a Channel, Structure or Singles from search?

Tags: templating, search

I'm trying to figure out how to exclude a Channel, Structure or Singles from my search results.

Currently I have the default example from Craft

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.search(query).order('score') %}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work for a single section:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('not news').search(query).order('score') %}
```

to exclude more sections:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section([
    'and', 'not news', 'not blog'
]).search(query).order('score') %}
```